# Why am I getting 404 error in Flask?

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, flask

I'm a Django developer learning Flask. I'm pretty new to how things work in Flask. I'm getting a 404 with the following code when I visit `localhost:5000`. Could someone explain why I'm getting this:

*The requested URL was not found on the server.
If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.*

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////media/workdrive/workspace/purkinje/temp.db'
app.debug = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category', backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, title, body, category, pub_date=None):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        if pub_date is None:
            pub_date = datetime.utcnow()
        self.pub_date = pub_date
        self.category = category

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.title

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r> % self.name'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    posts = Post().query.all()
    return render_template('templates/index.html', posts=posts)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're calling `app.run()` before registering your handler. You should move the whole `if __name__ == '__main__'` block to the bottom of the script.

Comment: I figured it was something simple like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I executed `send_from_directory` with wrong path to file inside my view function