# Flask not registering routes

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code that doesn't seem to be registering routes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys,json
from flask import Flask, url_for

class Foo:

    server = Flask(__name__)
    mountpoint = "/api"

    def __init__(self,startup="run",config="",mountpoint="/api"):
        self.mountpoint = mountpoint
        self.startup = startup
        self.server = server

    @server.route("/test")
    def test(self):
        return "Hello world!"

    def getEndpoints(self):
        server = self.server
        with server.test_request_context():
            print url_for('test')

    def start(self,**kwargs):
        getattr(self.server,self.startup)(**kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mon = Foo()
    mon.getEndpoints()
    mon.start(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

If I don't call "getEndpoints" things *seem* to run just fine, but /test returns a 404.  When calling "getEndpoints" it returns a build error.  I'm guessing it's something simple like [Why am I getting 404 error in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024374/why-am-i-getting-404-error-in-flask) or something scope related, but I'm still relatively new to python so I'm a little lost as to what the problem might be.

Comment: What is this code? Flask doc never offers tutorial code as same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on my machine and found that removing the `self` argument from your test function caused /test to work fine. In my experience, the arguments to your view functions are values passed in by the `@route` decorator.

See the [Flask docs on routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing).

Comment: Could you provide an example?  I've read over the flask docs and as far as I can tell I'm doing everything correctly.  "self" is passed as an argument because it's a class method.  Removing "self" doesn't seem to help for me.  Still getting "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('test', {}, None)"

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints) or [Application Factories](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/)? I don't have experience with them unfortunately, but I know that they can be used to make multiple instances of a Flask app. Sorry if that's not very helpful.

Comment: [This extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/) also looks promising and similar to the code you wrote.